# Opencv Circle Detection - RAM loading

Tags: c++, opencv

I have recently been doing some circle detection in OpenCV and I have had some great success. The code below works wonderfully in C++ on a 32-bit platform. I do however have one small problem; as the program runs my RAM loads continues to load up. For example, when I start the program I am at 250mb, 30 seconds later I am at about 800mb. This continues and eventually overflows to the hard drive. I have tried to move the cvReleaseCapture inside the while loop but I just get the old "Exception at memory location....". Any ideas how I can clean this up? Thanks a lot. Here's the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <math.h>


int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    CvCapture *capture = 0;
    IplImage  *img = 0;
    int       key = 0;
CvFont font;
cvInitFont(&font, CV_FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,1.0,1.0,0,1,CV_AA);

capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( 0 );

if ( !capture ) {
    fprintf( stderr, "Cannot open initialize webcam!\n" );
    return 1;
} 

cvNamedWindow( "result", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

while( key != 'q' ) {
    img = cvQueryFrame( capture ); 
    IplImage* gray = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(img), 8, 1 );
    CvMemStorage* storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
    cvCvtColor( img, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
    cvSmooth( gray, gray, CV_GAUSSIAN, 9, 9 );
    CvSeq* circles = cvHoughCircles( gray, storage, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 2, gray-    >height/4, 200, 100, 20, 100 );
    int i;
    for( i = 0; i < circles->total; i++ )
    {
         float* p = (float*)cvGetSeqElem( circles, i );
         //cvCircle( img, cvPoint(cvRound(p[0]),cvRound(p[1])), 2, CV_RGB(0,255,0), -1, 8, 0 );
         cvCircle( img, cvPoint(cvRound(p[0]),cvRound(p[1])), cvRound(p[2]), CV_RGB(0,255,0), 2, 8, 0 );
         cvLine (img, cvPoint(cvRound(p[0]+40),cvRound(p[1])), cvPoint(cvRound(p[0]),cvRound(p[1])), CV_RGB(0,255,0), 1, CV_AA,0);
         cvLine (img, cvPoint(cvRound(p[0]),cvRound(p[1]+40)), cvPoint(cvRound(p[0]),cvRound(p[1])), CV_RGB(0,255,0), 1, CV_AA,0);
         cvLine (img, cvPoint(cvRound(p[0]-40),cvRound(p[1])), cvPoint(cvRound(p[0]),cvRound(p[1])), CV_RGB(0,255,0), 1, CV_AA,0);
         cvLine (img, cvPoint(cvRound(p[0]),cvRound(p[1]-40)), cvPoint(cvRound(p[0]),cvRound(p[1])), CV_RGB(0,255,0), 1, CV_AA,0);
         cvPutText(img, "Meow",cvPoint(cvRound(p[0]+45),cvRound(p[1]+45)), &font, CV_RGB(0,0,255)); 

    }


    if( !img ) break;       
    cvShowImage( "result", img ); 
    key = cvWaitKey( 1 );
    cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
}

cvDestroyWindow( "result" );
cvReleaseCapture( &capture );    

return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the `cvReleaseCapture` inside the while loop. Instead, you should have

```
cvReleaseMemStorage(storage);
cvReleaseImage(gray);
```

And you should probably move the `if (!img) break;` line up so it reads:

```
img = cvQueryFrame(capture);
if (!img) break;
```

**Edit**

Actually, instead of constantly creating and then destroying `gray`, you should do an initial capture (`img = cvQueryFrame(capture);`) outsid eof the `while` loop. Then create `gray` in the normal way. Then you don't have to keep creating it in the `while` loop, which is why you're running out of memory (you're creating an new image every iteration without releasing it).

So

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <math.h>


int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    CvCapture *capture = 0;
    IplImage  *img = 0;
    int       key = 0;
    CvFont font;
    cvInitFont(&font, CV_FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,1.0,1.0,0,1,CV_AA);

    capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( 0 );

    if ( !capture ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "Cannot open initialize webcam!\n" );
        return 1;
    } 

    cvNamedWindow( "result", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

    img = cvQueryFrame( capture );
    if (!img) 
        exit(1);
    IplImage* gray = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(img), 8, 1 );
    CvMemStorage* storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);

    while( key != 'q' ) {
        img = cvQueryFrame( capture ); 
        if( !img ) break;  


        cvCvtColor( img, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
        cvSmooth( gray, gray, CV_GAUSSIAN, 9, 9 );
        CvSeq* circles = cvHoughCircles( gray, storage, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 2, gray-        >height/4, 200, 100, 20, 100 );
        int i;
        for( i = 0; i < circles->total; i++ )
        {
            float* p = (float*)cvGetSeqElem( circles, i );
            //cvCircle( img, cvPoint(cvRound(p[0]),cvRound(p[1])), 2, CV_RGB(0,255,0), -1, 8, 0 );
            cvCircle( img, cvPoint(cvRound(p[0]),cvRound(p[1])), cvRound(p[2]), CV_RGB(0,255,0), 2, 8, 0 );
            cvLine (img, cvPoint(cvRound(p[0]+40),cvRound(p[1])), cvPoint(cvRound(p[0]),cvRound(p[1])), CV_RGB(0,255,0), 1, CV_AA,0);
            cvLine (img, cvPoint(cvRound(p[0]),cvRound(p[1]+40)), cvPoint(cvRound(p[0]),cvRound(p[1])), CV_RGB(0,255,0), 1, CV_AA,0);
            cvLine (img, cvPoint(cvRound(p[0]-40),cvRound(p[1])), cvPoint(cvRound(p[0]),cvRound(p[1])), CV_RGB(0,255,0), 1, CV_AA,0);
            cvLine (img, cvPoint(cvRound(p[0]),cvRound(p[1]-40)), cvPoint(cvRound(p[0]),cvRound(p[1])), CV_RGB(0,255,0), 1, CV_AA,0);
            cvPutText(img, "Meow",cvPoint(cvRound(p[0]+45),cvRound(p[1]+45)), &font, CV_RGB(0,0,255)); 

        }

        cvShowImage( "result", img ); 
        key = cvWaitKey( 1 );

    }
    cvReleaseMemStorage(storage);
    cvReleaseImage(gray);
    cvDestroyWindow( "result" );
    cvReleaseCapture( &capture );    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks a lot my computer doesnt overheat after a minute of this program.

Comment: Sweet. You're new to stackoverflow; the next course of action here is to upvote my answer and select it as correct ;)